# How to send an email after finishing a chain of queued jobs (Laravel 5.5)?

Tags: laravel, notifications, jobs, laravel-5.5

What would be the best approach to send an email notification to a user after my chain of jobs are finished ?

I am using Laravel 5.5 & horizon queues.

**My method where user is being validated and a chain of jobs are being fired:**

```
        public function activateUser($token)
        {
            if ($user = $this->activationService->activateUser($token)) {


                CheckIfDown::withChain([
     (new ScanOne($user))->onQueue('new-user'),
     (new ScanTwo($user))->onQueue('new-user'),
     (new ScanThree($user))->onQueue('new-user'),
     (new FirstScanFinished($user))->onQueue('new-user') // What I've tried - this job should send an email from it's handle() method.

                ])->dispatch($user)->onQueue('new-user');


                return redirect('/login')->with('message', 'You have successfully completed the registration process!');
                //            return redirect($this->redirectPath());
            }
            abort(404);
        }
```

These specific chain of jobs are only fired once the user validates his email address. Email should be sent only once.

**FirstScanFinished handle method**

```
public function handle()
{
    $message = (new FirstScanFinished($this->user));
    $email = $this->user->email;
    Mail::to($email)
        ->send($message);
}
```

All the jobs appears to be successfully fired, but I don't get any email in my mailtrap(just to note all my smtp settings are good and emails in other places are firing of without any problems). I also don't get any error in my logs. How should I approach this ?

Comment: Try debugging yourself, change driver to sync, and hit it with bunch of `dd()`s, and `\Log::info('messages')`

Comment: ErrorException: Creating default object from empty value in /var/www/html/brand-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Queueable.php:98  <-- so managed to finally get an error, still trying to understand what's really wrong here .  @Kyslik